# Why isn't Flutterflow not connecting with Supabase when I add a user?

Tags: basic-authentication, supabase, flutterflow

I've created a new project in Supabase and created 2 tables with RLS enabled and policies that give all access to authenticated user and only uses email as the authentication provider. All email verification is disables.
I also created a project in Flutterflow that appears to be correctly integrated with Supabase since I do see data from both of my Supabase tables.
[image: Flutterflow Supabase dialog]

The next image shows the Flutterflow authentication dialog:
[image]

Here's the createAccount page:

[image]

And finally here's the Flutterflow Action that should execute the Supabase add account logic:

[image]

When I run the app in preview mode and enter all the required information, Supabase does not add the user. Also, Supabase does not return an error to Flutterflow if the passwords don't match.
What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - run the Flutterflow app in "Test" mode, not "Preview". Preview just gives a fast view of the UI but it doesn't execute any code. Running in "Test" mode does create the account in Supabase.